# Is Swift incapable of specializing generic types with generic types?

Tags: json, swift, generics, alamofire, objectmapper

I am working with a JSON API (Reddit) using Alamofire + AlamofireObjectMapper, as well as ObjectMapper. I am working on creating the model and have a proposed solution which is not working as expected. I'll do my best to explain...

The JSON response I am receiving has a base class `Thing` as follows

```
class Thing<T where T:Mappable>: Mappable {

    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var kind: String?
    var data: T?

    required init?(_ map: Map) {}

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- map["id"]
        name <- map["name"]
        kind <- map["kind"]
        data <- map["data"]
    }
}
```

The `data` property varies depending on the type of request I am making. In this particular case, it should be of type `Listing` as follows.

```
class Listing<T where T: Mappable>: Mappable {

    var before: String?
    var after: String?
    var modhash: String?
    var children: [Thing<T>]?

    required init?(_ map: Map) {}

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        before   <- map["before"]
        after    <- map["after"]
        modhash  <- map["modhash"]
        children <- map["children"]
    }
}
```

The `children` property is an array of `Thing` objects, however with `data` as a different type, in this case `Post`

```
class Post: Mappable {
    var author: String?
    var creationDate: Int?
    var name: String?
    var numberOfComments: Int?
    var score: Int?
    var text: String?
    var stickied: Int?
    var subreddit: String?
    var title: String?
    var url: String?
    var preview: Images?

    required init?(_ map: Map) {}

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        author <- map["author"]
        creationDate <- map["created_utc"]
        name <- map["name"]
        numberOfComments <- map["num_comments"]
        score <- map["score"]
        text <- map["selftext"]
        stickied <- map["stickied"]
        subreddit <- map["subreddit"]
        title <- map["title"]
        url <- map["url"]
        preview <- map["preview"]
    }
}
```

Using the AlamofireObjectMapper extension, to parse the JSON response to my custom model, we use

```
public func responseObject<T : Mappable>(keyPath: String? = default, completionHandler: Alamofire.Response<T, NSError> -> Void) -> Self
```

where the it is expecting a generic type. I will use a type defined as `Response<Thing<Listing<Post>>, NSError>` as follows...

```
RedditAPIService.requestSubReddit(subReddit: nil, withSortType: .Hot, afterPost: nil, postsAlreadyShown: nil).responseObject { (response: Response<Thing<Listing<Post>>, NSError>) -> Void in
            if let value = response.result.value {
                print(value.kind)
            }
        }
```

The problem I am seeing is corrupt data on the `Listing` object.

[image: DebugIMG]

I am expecting only 1 value in the `children` object, not > 900 Zillion!

I know I can subclass `Thing` and `Listing` to use specific types, but I also am curious why this does not work as expected. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds interesting. What if you print out the `data.children.count`? Might be a debugger issue?

Comment: Interesting, it prints out exactly what I am expecting... count is 1, all the data is there. This is a debugger issue...